# How to remove the image noises in this photo with morphology while making the backgorund white and without reducing the text readability too much?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise-reduction

This must be done in MATLAB. I tried median filter by [5 5], Tried imerode, imdilate but texts are getting worse. I even tried strel with line, square, disk, degreed line, anything you name it. Can't do much. Isn't there a way to do it without damaging the text?

[image]

Comment: why you don't share what you have tried (in code) [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using **Morphological closing** you will get a somehow acceptable results:

[image]

```
% Image
img = imread('Noisy_Text.jpg');

% Structuring Element
SE=zeros(3,3);
SE(1,1)=1;
SE(1,3)=1;
SE(2,2)=1;
SE(3,1)=1;
SE(3,3)=1;
Imdilte=imclose(img,SE);

figure();
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(Imdilte)
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(img);
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the almost same results. Aren't there any better methods than this without damaging the text much?

Comment: @Stayheuh maybe there is but I don't know how, also you can change structuring element to see if there is any improvement